# Using replace in T-SQL where condition does not seem to work

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Environment: SQL Server 2017

Here is a working T-SQL query:

```
SELECT replace(email, '.', '') as EMAIL
FROM usermaster
WHERE email = 'abc.def@gmail.com'
```

When executed, this query returns `abcdef@gmail.com` as expected.

For my needs, I have to ignore dots when comparing email. Here is the query that I want:

```
SELECT email
FROM usermaster
WHERE replace(email, '.', '') = 'abcdef@gmail.com'
```

However, this query does not return me any records. As is obvious from the previous query, I should be getting `abc.def@gmail.com` as my output. What is it that I am missing? Regards.

Comment: Check the initial output again. One of those assertions is probably false.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to treat `name@some.com` and `name@somec.om` as being the same thing?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen as always, requirements specification is the basis of everything. Messing up at that step cost an arm. +1 !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you're getting the .COM in your first query?

```
SELECT email
FROM usermaster
WHERE replace(email, '.', '') = 'abcdef@gmailcom'  -- notice no .com
```